# How to change the order of date and subtract days

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a date :

```
var today = new Date();
```

But I need to have it in yyyy/mm/dd format, without the time. 
I have found something like that:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;
```

Which works for format, but I still want to subtract days from it, for example 4 days.
Any idea how would I achieve that?

Comment: You can simply do `var today = new Date(); today.setDate(today.getDate()-4);` and the use the same format as above on `today`.

Answer (score 1):

Many people use moment.js when working with dates.

```js
const now = moment();
console.log(now.format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
console.log(now.subtract(4, 'days').format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```